# backward/forward validation in optimistic concurrency control

Tags: concurrency, transactions, distributed-system, optimistic-locking

I am new to "concurrency" & "transactions" and I feel a little confused about backward/forward validation in optimistic concurrency control. Just take backward validation for an example. Suppose Tv is the transaction being validated and Ti is the committed transactions. I was wondering why we just check the Tv's read set vs.Ti's write set . Why don't we check Tv's write set vs.Ti's write set and Tv's write set vs.Ti's read set too? Since write-write and write-read are also conflict operations...Any explanation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Validation uses the *read*-*write* conflict rules to ensure that the scheduling of a particular transaction is serially equivalent to all overlapping transations. This means that once entered the validation phase, no changes to *read*/*write* sets can be further performed.

There are 3 rules that need to be satisfied by any two transactions T<sub>i</sub> and T<sub>j</sub>, where i < j ( T<sub>i</sub> entered validation phase before T<sub>j</sub>):

1. T<sub>i</sub> must not read objects written by T<sub>j</sub>
2. T<sub>j</sub> must not read objects written by T<sub>i</sub>
3. T<sub>i</sub> must not write objects written by T<sub>j</sub> and
   T<sub>j</sub> must not write objects written by T<sub>i</sub>

Backward validation **assumes** that all *read* operations of T<sub>i</sub> were performed before validation of T<sub>j</sub> started. This means that T<sub>i</sub> is already in the validation phase. **(rule 1 is satisfied)**

During validation of T<sub>j</sub>, the *read* set of T<sub>j</sub> is checked against *write* set of T<sub>i</sub>. If there is no overlap, then **(rule 2 is satisfied)**.

If Rule 1 and Rule 2 are satified, Rule 3 is implicitly satisfied. All the changes commited will be done sequentially because T<sub>i</sub> entered validation phase before T<sub>j</sub>. T<sub>i</sub>'s *write* set will be validated and commited before T<sub>j</sub>'s *write* set.

Answer (score -1):

- backward validation of Tv:

  - read operations of earlier overlapping transactions (performed
    before validation of Tv) cannot be affected by the writes ot Tv.
    The validation checks Tv's read set against write sets of earlier
    transactions, failing if there is any conflict;
- forward validation of Tv:

  - write set of Tv is compared with the read sets of all overlapping
    active transactions;
  - differently from backward validation, in forward validation there
    are choices of which transaction to abort (Tv or any of the
    conflicting active transactions);